# c++ searching for a node in a tree

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, target

In my program I am recursively trying to find a node in a tree while given a target, but i cant get it to work!

```
    Stree::Node * Stree::find_node(Node* cur, string target)
{
    Node *tmp = cur;;
    if(cur == NULL || tmp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(cur->m_city == target || tmp->m_city == target)
        return cur;
    if(find_node(tmp->m_left, target))
    {
        return tmp;
    }
    else return find_node(cur->m_right, target);
```

Comment: What goes wrong? And would you mind giving us a minimal complete example?

Comment: Why do you use a tree if you're going to do a linear search anyway? The point of a tree is normally to get O(log N) searching, but you're not doing that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
if(find_node(tmp->m_left, target))
{
    return tmp;
}
```

You should return result of `find_node` there:

```
tmp = find_node(cur->m_left, target);
if (tmp) return tmp;
```

Comment: Don't feed the help vampires.